# apply different style to odd divs

Tags: html, css, razor, sass

I'm working with owl-caroussel plugin, and I need to apply a border-right style to odd divs, when I apply this selector it just adds the border to all divs of class  "info", it doesn't matter if it's even or odd:

```
   section#presentation section#last div.info:nth-of-type(odd){
               border-right: 1px solid #ede1d9;
          }
```

I must be doing something wrong, this is the code in the razor view:

```
<section id="last">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 newswidth">                   
                <div id="news-wrap">
                    <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <!--item-->
                        @{  var counter = 0;}
                        @foreach (var itemBlogList in Model.BlogList)
                        {

                            if (counter == 4)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            <div class="info">
                                <a href="@itemBlogList.Link" class="title">@itemBlogList.Title</a>
                                <div class="credentials">
                                    <div class="author">PETER SCHULTZ</div>
                                    <div class="date">@itemBlogList.PublishDate</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cut">
                                    @Html.Raw(@itemBlogList.Text)
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            counter++;
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
</section>
```

How can I add that border to only odd divs of class "info"?

Comment: Can you post the compiled view?

Comment: Your code actually seems correct. I'd suggest enforcing border to be !important and see if it's not a priority issue. Or change the background, as a Proof of Concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

```css
.test:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this selector instead:

```
section#presentation section#last .owl-carousel > div:nth-child(odd){
   border-right: 1px solid #ede1d9;
}
```

Yours will count *all* DIVs, (nth-of-*type*, i.e. DIV), not just the ones with class `.info`

Answer (score 0):

To get the odd ones use this pseudo class

```
 .info:nth-child(2n-1) {
     your styles
 }
```